# Exporting data from SQL to Excel file

Tags: sql, excel, export-to-excel, vba

I am facing issue with the macro enabled excel file(XLTM extension). I am running xp_cmdshell command, command is working fine, i am able to copy the data into excel file. But when i try to open the excel file with it is giving error - file format or file is not valid,verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file format matches the format of the file.

Comment: Are you creating an "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook" file (i.e. "xlsm" extension) or an "Excel Macro-Enabled Template" file (i.e. "xltm" extension)?

Comment: There is already a Excel Macro-Enabled Template" file, i need to push the SQL table data into that file...Before pushing the data to the file, the excel file opens fine, after pushing the data to the file when i try to open it gives the error message.

Comment: It sounds like you are actually **replacing** the Template file with a Workbook file, but keeping the "xltm" extension.  (That's the error message you would get when you change an "xlsm" extension to "xltm".)  As a test, rename the file to have an "xlsm" extension and see if Excel happily opens it.

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: OK, I guess it's not what I was thinking of.  I think you will need to show the code you are using to modify the "xltm" file.

Comment: Please refer following link [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/noTcKHgNBOt)